# Get submit button value onsubmit event

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events, onsubmit

I have a strange edge-case, let me try to describe it:

I have a form with multiple submit buttons with different values. The submit value is important in my backend. I want to intercept a form submit (using `onsubmit`) do an asynchronous task and continue the event.

Sadly calling `Form.prototype.submit()` does not work, because the information which button was clicked is lost. Of course I can emulate that data, but just adding a hidden input, but I don't know how to figure out which button was clicked in the `onsubmit` event.

If you need an example this is where I am trying to solve it:
https://github.com/codingjoe/django-s3file/blob/master/s3file/static/s3file/js/s3file.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you dynamically submit the form, you can do it differently than calling `form.submit`. You can just trigger the `click` event of whichever submit button you need to. Then, in a `click` event handler for the submit buttons, you can assign a value to your hidden form field with the appropriate data.

Also, know that if you just give your submit buttons a `name` attribute with a unique value and they will deliver their `value` as part of the form's data that gets submitted.

Comment: Thanks you for the quick response, that does seem to work. Great!